# Sizing a diode for a desired current and switching capabilities

Tags: diodes

I was planning to use the following circuit with a 1N4148 diode for a PWM between 0.5kHz upto 30kHz:

[image]

In another forum someone mentioned 1N4148 is too small and it needs to be replaced with a bigger one, but fast with 1A DC rated which would be more than enough.

But in simulation very small current passes through diode:

[image]

And this is the MOSFET power plot:

[image]

What would be the reason to go for a bigger one?

I'm hesitating between a [1N4933](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88508/1n4933.pdf) and a [1N4001-T](http://1N4001).
Both has 1A "Maximum average forward rectified current".

1N4001-T is called Switching Diode, 1N4933 is called Fast Switching Plastic Rectifier.

Are they both fast enough for this circuit where PWM can be up to 30kHz?
I don't know how can I approach this issue of choosing the right diode here.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this too much and thus missing one important detail: the MOSFET also has a diode which will also short the flyback pulse into the supply. Speed is not such an issue here, 30 kHz is quite low frequency. If you use a slow diode, part of the flyback pulse will be caught by the diode in the NMOS. Use the 1N4933 if you're paranoid but honestly the 1N4001 will suffice. A 1N4148 might also cut the mustard but if not then it will be more trouble later than going for the safe option now which is a 1N4001.

Comment: But how did you conclude quantitatively that 1N4001 fast recovery enough for 30kHz application? What should I compare next time if I have a xHz switching? In data sheet where should I look for?

Comment: I could also ask you why it would not be fast enough. You want a strong relation between diode speed and switching frequency. It's not that simple. The diode only needs to do something when the NMOS switches off. Then the diode must short the flyback pulse. It takes some time for the diode to start conducting. In that time a reverse voltage appears across the NMOS. If it is a very sensitive device this must not last long so you need a fast diode. A power NMOS with its own diode can handle a lot more in that respect.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie wrong.... The diode in the mosfet only protects it from being driven with a negative Vds it will not protect it from the top going up to very high voltages when it turns off. Which is the flyback voltage/

Comment: I know, and the internal diode is required, but that is not what the flyback diode is for. The latter also needs to be able to handle the full currents involved, especially in a PWM situation where the inductance can mean it's on for the entire mosfet off cycle.

Comment: It might be that the NMOS diode acts as a zener diode so it does protect but in reverse (breakdown) mode. I have seen Power MOSFETs where it is allowed to use the build-in diode as flyback protection.

Comment: anyhow.. I agree, if your simulation is to be believed, even the 1N4148 will work. Other issue to watch out for is the MOSFET being faster than the recovery time of the diode. When that happens you can get some nasty shoot through current spikes.

Comment: Yes, in this case the 1N4148 is too small. Not because of it's forward current, but because of the reverse recovery current. The 1N4148 is a small signal diode, as a rectifier for signals with low power/current. In this case, you get a large current discharging the space charge of the diode when the FET switches on.

Comment: BTW Are those values for the inductors real?

Comment: @Trevor Good point. I added myself. I dont know the real values. Here is the magnet: https://www.schukat.com/schukat/pdf.nsf/index/93CC9B3FCD64452EC1257584004786F9/$file/ITS-MS_5030.pdf Do you think I should set them to 1mH instead?

Comment: If I set inductors to 1mH, the didoe current goes up to 1.1A

Comment: OMG you need to find out the actual inductance. (and resistance). Change it to 1mH  in your simulation and look at how it changes things...

Comment: Also be aware inductance will change.. A LOT when the magnet is stuck on, or close to, a bit of steel or whatever.

Comment: I get completely different results, I will add it to the question just a moment

Comment: Seriously.. before you go any further find out the real/worst case values for the magnet. Call the vendor, or buy a few and measure them. The rest of this question is academic without that information, as was your previous question.

Comment: You may want to go to the source too http://www.red-magnetics.com/en/index.php Looks like they also give you samples if ask.

Comment: @Trevor Because of hesitation, the others decided to vary the magnet strengths with a 24V variable supply. So I cancelled doing this circuit, thanks anyway. They hurry so much and dont give me enough time to even investigate.